# How to Show Badge count on App icon in Xamarin Cross-Plotform Application for both Android and iOS

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am trying to add the icon badge in iOS application when a notification is received.
I have a PCL Project, And i have installed `Xam.Plugin.Badge` from **Nuget** , so in my `AppDelegate.cs` file i have added following line of code for iOS

```
CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(number);
```

But Badge is not showing on App icon when running the app in Mac simulator.
Can any one correct me where i am doing wrong please.

Best regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official documentation [ApplicationIconBadgeNumber](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber/), On iOS8+ we need to register for user notifications to be able to set the application icon badge number:

```
//Register this in the Appdelegate
UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Badge, null);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
```

Then you can change the app's badge in the PCL with `CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(number);`

Moreover if you want to set the badge on the native iOS platform, you can try `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = number;` directly.

Comment: Thanks Land for the reply, can i test this badge count with Mac simulator or need any physical device to test

Comment: @srinivaschalla Yes, you can test it on simulator.

Comment: public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();            
            UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Badge, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(10);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);        
        }

Comment: Hi land, I am using above block of code in my Appdelegate.cs file, And i am checking in iOS 6 11.2 version simulater in Mac, but badge in showing in App icon

Comment: Thanks Land it worked for me, Thank you very much
it is working perfectly for iOS,  Here how can i work with the same for Android